# Parse XML to get a list or dictionary of data values from crowd API

Tags: python, xml, xpath, atlassian-crowd

I have this sample XML response from Atlassian Crowd Rest API and the real one will be a lot bigger. I am trying to parse the XML using Python ElementTree.

Here is the XML file named `crowd.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<memberships>
 <membership group="crowd-administrators">
  <users>
   <user name="admin" />
   <user name="bilcy@abc.com" />
  </users>
  <groups>
  </groups>
 </membership>
 <membership group="developers">
  <users>
   <user name="johns" />
   <user name="millers" />
   <user name="peeryj" />
  </users>
  <groups>
  </groups>
 </membership>
</memberships>
```

In this API response from Atlassian Crowd, I need to extract the list of all the group names like crowd-administrators and developers. I need a list or dictionary of all the user names in each group. I also need to list all the users in a particular group as well.

I am trying to use XPath but am unable to get the values of the group name and user names.

```
def parseXML(xmlfile):
    tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
    root = tree.getroot()
    users = tree.findall(".//user[@name='admin']")
    print(users)

parseXML("crowd.xml")
```

This doesn't print anything.

I was able to printout the entire XML with `ET.fromstring`

```
def parseXML2():
    url = 'http://localhost:8095/crowd/rest/usermanagement/latest/group/membership'
    response = requests.get(url, auth=("app-name", "passwd"))
    xml_response = ET.fromstring(response.content)
    print(xml_response)

parseXML2()
```

I would have used JSON output for this, but this API doesn't support JSON output.
Not sure how I can extract the group names and users in them. Any help with extracting the data is appreciated. TIA

Comment: worked for me with OP's code sample. `lxml` is perhaps a better package to use.

Comment: based on the xml you have posted - what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to extract the list of all the group names like crowd-administrators and developers. I need a list or dictionary of all the user names in each group.

Something like the below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict

xml = '''<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<memberships>
 <membership group="crowd-administrators">
  <users>
   <user name="admin" />
   <user name="bilcy@abc.com" />
  </users>
  <groups>
  </groups>
 </membership>
 <membership group="developers">
  <users>
   <user name="johns" />
   <user name="millers" />
   <user name="peeryj" />
  </users>
  <groups>
  </groups>
 </membership>
</memberships>
'''

data = defaultdict(list)
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for m in root.findall('.//membership'):
  group_name = m.attrib['group']
  for u in m.findall('.//user'):
      data[group_name].append(u.attrib['name'])
print(data)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'crowd-administrators': ['admin', 'bilcy@abc.com'], 'developers': ['johns', 'millers', 'peeryj']})
```